# Having trouble passing props with <Link> in react-router 3

Tags: react-router, prop

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious, but I'm having some issues with my React components. I'm setting it up so that a grandparent is passing down props to a grandchild (in my test example it's just a string) so that it will be displayed in the grandchild but not the child.

The grandparent is IconsContainer, and it passes props down to each icon in the IconComponent. The icons link to PhotoDisplayComponent. That's where the string will be displayed. I'm not coming up with any errors, but the string is not being displayed and it's skipping my debugger. Other text hardcoded into the PhotoDisplayComponent does render.

I'm aware that it looks like there is nothing that the  tag is linking to. I'm using flaticon icons, which are generated via class, so it displays on the page showing these icons with a link attached to them. If it helps to have a visual, this is a work in progress: https://fotou.herokuapp.com/

IconsContainer(parent)

```
import React from "react";
import IconComponent from "../components/IconComponent"
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class IconsContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="icon-list">
        <IconComponent
          class="flaticon-black icon cat"
          test="test"
        />
        <IconComponent
          class="flaticon-animals icon dog"
        />
        <IconComponent
          class="flaticon-dove icon bird"
        />
        <IconComponent
        />
        <IconComponent
          class="flaticon-drink icon food"
        />
        <IconComponent
          class="flaticon-mountain icon scenery"
        />
        <IconComponent
          class="flaticon-city icon buliding"
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default IconsContainer
```

IconComponent (child)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class IconComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {
     test: this.props.test
    }
  }

  render() {
    let test = this.state.test

    return(
      <Link to="/photo_display" className={this.props.class}></Link>
    )
  }
}

export default IconComponent;
```

PhotoDisplayComponent (grandchild)

```
import React from "react"
import IconComponent from "../components/IconComponent"

class PhotoDisplayComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      test: this.props.test
    }
  }

  render() {
    let test = this.state.test
    return(
      <div>
         <h1>Photo</h1>
         <p>{test}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default PhotoDisplayComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

PhotoDisplayComponent isn't really a grandchild component, as IconComponent doesn't import it and render it as part of the component.
Containing a component inside a component and using a link which routes to a different component are not the same thing, and linking to a component doesn't necessarily mean it has any relation to the linking component.

Thus, the props of the parent and child aren't propagated to the grandchild, but instead the "grandchild" is rendered independently, with no passed props.

Comment: Ok. Do you have any suggestions of what could work instead?

Comment: You could use the real father's state and then pass his props on to PhotoDisplayComponent. If you're using redux you could save it through the reducers, or just keep it in the state. On route change you can change the state and pass the props as desired.